# .htaccess Mask Domain and hide url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I am trying to get a subdomain to show to contents of another domain, with the ability to go to any area of the other domain i.e. all directories

So for example I would like my client to go to "sub.domain-one.com" or more specifically "sub.exampledomain.com/client_name". I would like this to then show the content of "domain-two.com", my development server, without the client knowing.

I would also if possible like to keep the base domain of "sub.domain-one.com" to stay on my live server so that I can keep a index.php on that server. But this is only an extra wish :)

My current code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(sub.)?domain-one.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub.)?domain-one.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain-two.com/$1 [P,NC]
```

This code seems to work to an extent (it will let me go to sub.domain-one.com but if I go to sub.domain-one.com/client_name it will redirect my browser url to domain-two.com/client_name
But I need it hidden :(

Thanks heaps in advanced

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `ProxyPassReverse` in order to rewrite redirects from the proxied site to the site that you are proxying *from*. Unfortunately, you can't do this in an htaccess file. In the server/vhost config, you'll need to create a virtual host for "sub.domtain-one.com"/"domain-one.com", then use `ProxyPass`:

```
ProxyPass / http://domain-two.com/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://domain-two.com/
```

Comment: So I need to make modifications to the httpd.conf file on domain-two.com and add the relevant records.

And then add those two lines you gave me to the .htaccess at sub.domain-one.com

Is that correct?

Thanks heaps mate

Comment: @MutantTurtlez Yeah, otherwise if domain-two.com wants to redirect, you'll end up getting redirected to domain-two.com